# Insert row to filtered rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. I'm attempting to filter based on column L2 to the last row and add breaks based on criteria changes from A2 to the last row of the filtered column.

But it's running for the hidden rows as well. I'm thinking it's something simple I'm missing but any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Article State Change"
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    irow = rng.Row
    icol = rng.Column
Do
If Cells(irow + 1, icol) <> Cells(irow, icol) Then
   Cells(irow + 1, icol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
   Cells(irow + 1, icol).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
   irow = irow + 2
Else
   irow = irow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(irow, icol).Text = ""
```

Comment: When you set `rng`, the `SpecialCells` property does not transfer to each cell that you loop through.  You need to set the property to the entire range.  I also doubt that you have exactly 10K rows.  You should look into setting the last row or use `UsedRange` if the data is contiguous.

Comment: That was it! I knew it had to be something small I was missing! Thanks for your help! I've updated the code to reflect the corrections and answer.

Comment: Well, be grateful then and at least upvote Darrell's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following data:

[image]

If you now filter by `Article State Change` then your `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` results in a range consisting of 4 not contiguous areas `{1}, {7,8}, {11} and {17}`. Therefore you must loop through each of these areas first and then loop through all the rows in each area (using a second loop).

Also because inserting rows changes row numbers of the rows below the insert position, you need to loop from the bottom of your data to the top.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterAndInsert()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'better define by name: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("A1:O" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Article State Change"

    Dim FilteredData As Range
    Set FilteredData = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Dim iArea As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iArea = FilteredData.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop from last to first area
        For iRow = FilteredData.Areas(iArea).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop from last row to first row in each area
            With FilteredData.Areas(iArea).Rows(iRow) '<-- this represents the current row we are in the loop
                .Offset(RowOffset:=1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Offset(RowOffset:=1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
            End With
        Next iRow
    Next iArea

    'remove filters
    ws.Range("A1:O" & LastRow).AutoFilter
End Sub
```

So the result would be:

[image]